# Wordpress installation self deleted in server restart. SQL Tables gone too!

Tags: errors, installation, customization

I have or had in this case, two wordpress sites running on a Ubuntu 12.04 server edition which were installed over the weekend. After installation both sites were performing as expected, no problems. The mysql tables were populated and life was good.

This morning after a server restart, the mysql tables are gone and when entering the url to go to the sites wordpress is presenting the initial install page with the following appended in the url ... wp-admin/install.php.

My file permissions are as follows:
[image: File permissions for the WP installation]

For both sites, there is a dedicated user for the purposes of the database installation and credentials to keep information separate. Everything else is separate too like the installation directories and apache config files.

Has anyone experienced this before? Are there any other thoughts on what the problem is?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It sounds like your MySQL server did not automatically restart. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server

Comment: So that is just the problem. Mysql is running but the tables for the websites are empty. Ive never seen anything like this.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like it either. I have never seen tables disappear. Are the actual files present?

Comment: have you tried sudo service mysql restart? Sometimes that happens on my local server. It'll restart but mysql will not, saying the tables do not exist. A simple restart reloads them.

Comment: The actual files are present in the install directory. When the server restarted, MYSQL did not start which usually happens anyway. So, i then entered: sudo service mysql start, to get it going and for good measure did the same for apache. Thats when i looked at phpmyadmin and saw the tables  missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this happens when the owner for your SQL folder get's changed and you run a new WordPress install. Changing the owner back to the original user and restarting might get it back up and running.